# Git, "move" a commit exactly as it is without merge files

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset

in git I had a situation like this:

```
a - b - c - d - #be2c15
                    ^
```

I wanted to recover some files from the commit "a" so I did a reset SOFT without modify the working tree

```
a - b - c - d - #be2c15
^
```

Then I recovered the files marked as deleted.
 
At this point I had to reset back the index to #be2c15 and then do the commit but I made a mistake and committed the changes immediately like this:

```
a - b - c - d - #be2c15
 \
  #88ae59e
```

Now the commit #88ae59e contains exactly all that I want but is in the wrong position. How can I "move" it without touching any file that it contains?
Like this:

```
a - b - c - d - #be2c15 - #88ae59e
```

Comment: Isn't that a rebase? Or maybe a cherry-pick?

Comment: @melpomene A rebase would apply the diff from `a` to `#88ae59e` on top of `#be2c15`. That is something radically different from creating a new commit with the parrent `#be2c15` and the tree of `#88ae59e`, which I believe is what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `git rebase` could work (but depending on the changes in between merge conflicts might occur while doing the rebase).

After a

```
$ git rebase be2c15 88ae59e
```

and possibly some merge conflict fixing you might get what you wanted.

*Use `git rebase --abort` to revert back*

---

**But** if you wanted to recover some deleted files there might be an easier way to do this.

From the git documentation about [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

> ```
> git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…​
> ```
>
> When `<paths>` or `--patch` are given, git checkout **does not** switch branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit).

So

```
$ git checkout a -- path-to-folder/or/file/
```

will check out the `path-to-folder/or/file` as it was at the time of commit `a`.

Comment: But the checkout should move also the index to the designed commit right?
Actually I guess if there is a manner to get the exact content of the commit #88ae59e remaining in #be2c15.<br>
<br>
Otherwise I have to:<br>
1. Checkout #88ae59e<br>
2. Copy the working tree in a temp unversioned folder<br>
3. Checkout #be2c15<br>
4. Replace his working tree with the temp folder<br>
5. Commit it<br>
<br>
It seems strange to me that git doesn't provide a command to do this automatically

Comment: I hope my edit clarifies the usage of `git checkout -- some-file` a bit better/more.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, when the checkout command is executed in any case git does some operation in the working tree (asking how he have to proceed with the conflict)

Comment: Do you have uncommited changes in the file you want to recover with `git checkout -- path/to-file`? You would need to stage or commit them first.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to create a commit with the tree of `#88ae59e`, this command sequence should do the trick:

```
git checkout 88ae59e    #checkout the tree that you want to commit
#you should be in detached head state now
git reset --soft master #switch HEAD to the intended parent commit
#you should still be in detached head state now
git checkout master     #reattach to your branch so it will see the following commit
git commit ...
```

If you perform `git reset --soft` in detached head state, you won't leave detached head state, so you need to point your HEAD to the branch after the reset via a second `git checkout`.

Comment: All works as I would like till the checkout command. It doesn't only reattach the branch, it also try to merge the file in the working tree

Comment: I think, you should verify that your `HEAD` points to the same commit as your `master` by comparing the output of `git show -s HEAD` and `git show -s master`. These two must be identical; and if they are, `git checkout master` will be instantaneous and won't fail because it does not need to touch any files. (The only, and intended effect of the second `checkout` is to move from the `HEAD -> be2c15` state to the `HEAD -> master -> be2c15` state, so that the following `commit` will advance `master` and not just `HEAD`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that outside of git pretty easy to avoid any chance of conflicts or irritations:

```
git checkout 88ae59e
tar cf /tmp/tmp.tar --exclude=.git 
git checkout be2c15
tar xf /tmp/tmp.tar ; rm /tmp/tmp.tar
git add... ; git commit
```